Connect 3AWG ground to 10AWG copper ground
I have an emergency generator with a 10AWG green stranded copper ground wire. The generator is next to my main panel, which has a 3AWG solid copper ground which runs into the ground. Can I connect my small green ground to the big ground?
The ground wire is connected to the metal frame of the generator, and it's fine if the connection I make is permanent.

Is this copper ground wire not part of the generator cord? Or is this a hard-wired generator set?  Also, do you need this connection to be readily disconnectable, or are you OK with this being a permanent connection?

What do the generator's instructions say?  Normally if it's designed as a residential backup generator, the ground wire will go to the transfer switch that by design will have a suitable connection point for it.   Why are you having to improvise?

Thank you! I found that the Main Panel has a connector for the house's ground wire that also has a port for a ground wire. That solves my problem
